# Zoom to a specific point with pixi.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

Using pixi.js to make a 2D game, when the main player dies (because he hit a fox, a car or something else), I would like to zoom on it. The desire effect in mind is kind of the end of a level in super meat boy.

Check it, it's between 19:20 and 19:22 : http://youtu.be/3VKWn41Bqss?t=19m20s

I have a `worldLayer` variable that is a `DisplayObjectContainer`. This layer holds every element of the world, so I'm scaling it, like so, every frame :

```
this.worldLayer.scale.x += GAME.config.dead_zoom_speed;
this.worldLayer.scale.y += GAME.config.dead_zoom_speed;
```

Now you imagine that this piece of code zooms in direction of the coordinate (0,0), which is the top left corner of the screen. But of course, I'd like to zoom on the player, which is not is (0,0). It can be anywhere actually.

Zooming in on a specific point would be doable if the `DisplayObjectContainer` had the `anchor` property ; but it doesn't. [This code for exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/FnwS5/78/), with another lib than pixi, uses this technique : it modifies the anchor (called origin in this fiddle).

So my conclusion is, for zooming on a specific point, I have to use the `position` of the `worldLayer`. So for every frame :

- scale the world layer
- calculate the position of scaled worldlayer so that the viewport (with a fixed size, right) is centered on the main character.

This last point is where I'm stuck. How would you go and calculate the position ? My mind can't get around it.

With this comes the problem of centering without displaying the outer canvas. For instance, if the main character is near the right edge of the screen, it would not be totally centered on the viewport. But that's kind of another problem.

So I'd like to discuss that with you guys : have you ever had to implement such a feature ? how ? Am I missing something in the pixi.js API ?

Regards,

Comment: for follow up : https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1061